# JQUERY - Find how many img elements with a Class have the src set

Tags: jquery

I have 10 gallery photos with the class .photoPreview and I want to know how to check how many have the src set - eg: how many gallery images exist.

```
$('.photoPreview').attr('src')
```

I'm unsure how to get this value using Jquery. Maybe using find:

```
var number = find($('.photoPreview').attr('src'));
```

thankyou

---

HTML - my elements start like this if a gallery image isn't set:

```
<img src="" class="photoPreview" data-width="" data-height=""/>
```

Comment: I don't see the HTML you're using but what does check for a `src` attribute set do? All valid `img` elements should have the src set.

Comment: updated with HTML - thankyou :)

Comment: Yes, I'd highly advise not allowing empty img elements creep into your HTML. They're not valid, they'll cause rendering issues, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a css selector, like `:not([src=''])`, or the jquery equiv `.not()`. If you're referring to the `src` attribute of an IMG element though, they need the attribute set anyway.

`var number = $(".photoPreview:not([src=''])").length;`

Should work

Comment: This is far better approach

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1) Get the total number of images with class name `photoPreview`.

2) looping through those images.

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('photoPreview');  
var imagesWithSrc =0;
for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
  if (images[i].src != '')
     imagesWithSrc += 1;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by using the jquery method `.each()` you can pass a function to execute once for each element of the targeted selector

allowing you to do something like this:

```
var count = 0;

// loop through all elements in the array returned from the selector
$('.photoPreview').each(function(){

     // feel free to customize your conditional
     // to check the src however you like
     if ( $(this).attr('src').length > 0 ) { count++; } // increment the count

});

alert(count);
```

Comment: This method would work as well, but the `each` method has relatively poor performance and pulling all matching via a css selector allows this to be done in a single line of code.

Comment: agreed each will have poor performance in comparison - but the op said his limit was 10 photos and the difference in performance will be negligible... if the op is planning on doing something more practical outside of just counting the elements i thought this implementation would be much more versatile.  not worth a down-vote imo / many ways to skin a cat as they say